# Drag a text field created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, easeljs

JSFIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6q9hn5Ln/2/

Could someone show me how to drag multiple text boxes using the below script? At the moment this drags only 1 text box.

The problem is here:

```
var x = 0, y = 0;
interact('#outWrap_1') //how to set this to function with multiple text fields?
    .draggable({
        onmove: function (event) {
            x += event.dx;
            y += event.dy;

            event.target.style.webkitTransform =
            event.target.style.transform =
                'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';
        }
    })
    .inertia(true)
    .restrict({
        drag: "#OuterWrapper",
        endOnly: true
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap `interact` calling with `function`

```
function addInteract(interactId)
{
    var x = 0, y = 0;
    interact('#' + interactId).draggable({
        onmove: function (event) {
            x += event.dx;
            y += event.dy;
            event.target.style.webkitTransform =
            event.target.style.transform = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';
        }
    })
    .inertia(true)
    .restrict({
        drag: "#OuterWrapper",
        endOnly: true
    });
}
```

And just add

```
addInteract('outWrap_' + itmCount);
```

after `$('#OuterWrapper').append(outWrap);`

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q9hn5Ln/4/).

Comment: Yeah problem was of ID. ID work only for one element so only one element was draggable. So the ID should be unique for every element. :)

Comment: @KaranPatyal well, yes. There are only two ways: initialize `interact` for every new element with unique ID (like I've done), or use `interact` for elements' class (like APAD1 has suggested), but you should use separated `x` and `y` for every element nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Target the class `.tfz` instead since that class is applied to all the inputs.

```
interact('.tfz')
```

## [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q9hn5Ln/3/)

Comment: You didn't fix problem with same `x` and `y` for all draggable elements - so dragging looks weird. Can you update your answer?